# Strange 'Sleep' behaviour between systems

Tags: c++, winapi, timing

I have a program that uses `Sleep` Win32 API call to make a thread wait for a specific amount of time.
In short, it simulates a camera by sending images prefetched in memory. I'm using `Sleep` to simulate the frame rate -- `Sleep(1000 / fps)`

This works fine in my development system (Intel i5 (1st gen), Win7 64), but when I run it on another system (Intel i7-2600 - SandyBridge), the sleep times are totally different and inaccurate.

For example,
`Sleep(16)` sleeps for around `32ms`
`Sleep(3)` sleeps for `16ms`

In the past I thought there was a minimum sleep time in windows of `15ms` but I do not get that limitation on my dev system.

Any Ideas?

In addition, is there a better way to achieve the frame rate of my simulator?

Comment: Are you talking about the Win32 [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) function, or the C function [`sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/sleep.html) (note the casing of the 's')? Your description hints at the first, your spelling/naming and (rather generic) tags at the other.

Comment: @Christian.K -- Win32 `Sleep`

Answer (score 7):

The `sleep` function guarantees that you will sleep for at least the amount specified in the call. It causes the thread to suspend, allowing switches to other threads (governed by thread priorities) at the leisure of the scheduler. In other words, **the sleeping thread is *not* guaranteed to run immediately after the specified time has elapsed**, so using `sleep` for accurate timing should be avoided in the general case.

There are ways to achieve more accurate sleeping on Windows however. You can call `timeGetDevCaps` to determine the minimum supported timer resolution, and then call `timeBeginPeriod` once early in your application to set the timer resolution to its minimum. Be sure to call `timeEndPeriod` before your application exits.

For more information, see [the `Sleep` function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I've tried running `timeBeginPeriod` but it has no effect on the duration.

Comment: Are you sure it was successful, i.e. returned `TIMERR_NOERROR` [as described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on inccurate sleep behaviour or platform specific timer functions (which may work well, I don't know), you could structure this like a game loop.

Inside the loop you call a function to give you the current time. You figure out how long has elapsed since you drew the last frame and and decide when to render the next frame yourself exactly at the right time. During development you should measure the actual number of frames per second and display it.

With this approach, tt is easier to make your code cross platform and more accurate. Also your loop is in control rather than structuring your code as timer callbacks which you might also prefer.

The disadvantage is that a "busy wait" loop means your process will be using the CPU all the time unnecessarilly. To mitigate that you can yield the CPU in your loop by explicitly pumping user interface events in some way or perhaps using a shorter sleep :-).

If you want to learn more about this approach then start googling for material on game loops.

Here are some essential links:

http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

And a discussion on SO:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step